# initial steps for Paypal integration in Ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, paypal

I want to implement paypal in my app(because i can not use in-App purchase for physical goods).

I want to know the initial process to implement the paypal. i.e any app_key, money receiver account info etc.

I want to know what kind information will be required(which paypal will require) to start the paypal integration

How it will know that to whom account money to transfer.

Comment: Just follow this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

Comment: i have checked it. I dont know that is client id?. And where we use the information of reciver?

Comment: When you register with PayPal as developer you receive your client id. As I asked you just follow the steps in the sample codes. You should be able to do it very easily.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer don't forget to check mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to integrate Paypal with the iOS application i.e. 1) MPL - Mobile payments library : Launces Paypal window on the top of application window. 2) MECL - Mobile express checkout library : Launces in a webview

You can use MECL to implement PayPal. PayPal has provided sandbox inputs to be used. Once you develop the app, you need to submit it to paypal. Paypal will verify and test your application for various payment scenarios and security as well. Once they approve, they(Paypal) will provide you with a production env id number. USe that number in the app and upload it to app store.

And here is the link to PayPal Dev center which has all the details you need.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

Comment: Yes. But i want to know that where i have to add reciver info? how it will get to know to transfer money to correct reciever account

Comment: i am checking on same link that you have provided.  
i have checked it. I dont know that is client id?. And where we use the information of reciver?

Comment: Just follow the steps in the sample codes provided. It is really clear and step by step.

Comment: i have read whole doc. but dint find receiver info and app_key

Comment: You need to register your app with PayPal then you receive your app key. Just go to Dev center of PayPal and after registering your app you receive that.

Comment: ok. thanks. So it means the receiver account information will be filled when we register the app right? we need not to add receiver account info in our code right?

Comment: Yes. There are so many articles on their forum just for answering all of these questions. Just look it up if you have any further question.